# How to process xml response from flickr

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml, flickr

```
import flickrapi
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key,secret=api_secret)
r = flickr.photos_search(tags='e-waste', has_geo="1", per_page='100')
tree = ET.ElementTree(r) 

xml_input = etree.parse("response_clean.xml")  
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
links = str(transform(xml_input))
```

The idea of this little script is to get xml response from Flickr, and then use xsl file to process it further.

I want to convert `r` object (which is of type `lxml.etree._Element`) 
to `xml_input` (of type `lxml.etree._ElementTree`).

I used `tree = ET.ElementTree(r)` but result is of type `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree`.

I see that this is not exactly the same, but I don't understand the difference.

How should `r` be converted to `xml_input` ?

Answer (score 0):

The code creates `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree` because `ET` in the corresponding `import` statement references `xml.etree.ElementTree`. You should've used `etree.ElementTree` instead, which was imported from `lxml` :

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> raw ='''<root></root>'''
>>> r = etree.fromstring(raw)
>>> root = etree.ElementTree(r)
>>> type(r)
<type 'lxml.etree._Element'>
>>> type(root)
<type 'lxml.etree._ElementTree'>
```